# MPI executable fails for ArchLinux on Termux

Tags: configuration, mpi, termux, archlinux-arm

Why do I see the following error messages when executing `mpirun` on ArchLinux for Termux?

The same program executes on Termux without any glitches.

```
@localhost:/data/data/com.termux/files/home[root@localhost home] mpirun --allow-run-as-root
[localhost:06773] opal_ifinit: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) failed with errno=13
[localhost:06773] pmix_ifinit: ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) failed with errno=13
[localhost:06773] oob_tcp: problems getting address for index 83376 (kernel index -1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
No network interfaces were found for out-of-band communications. We require
at least one available network for out-of-band messaging.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A Google search reveals these links:

https://groups.google.com/g/trans-abyss/c/r5Z6w7BoNe4

https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/ralQnMWY/ompi-users-no-network-interfaces-were-found-for-out-of-band-communications

https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/kheNxePO/ompi-users-general-question-about-running-single-node-jobs

(export OMPI_MCA_oob=^tcp
removes the TCP related error.)

https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/6960

https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.open-mpi.org//msg32661.html

However, none of them appear to have a relevant solution.

Output to ifconfig and ip addr on ArchLinux for Termux

```
dummy0: flags=195<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::38a0:1bff:fe81:d4f5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 210 (210.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 17247  bytes 2062939 (1.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17247  bytes 2062939 (1.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p2p0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

rmnet_data0: flags=65<UP,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.140.58.138  netmask 255.255.255.252
        inet6 fe80::93a5:ad99:4660:adc4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 416796  bytes 376287723 (358.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 318293  bytes 69933666 (66.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

rmnet_data7: flags=65<UP,RUNNING>  mtu 2000
        inet6 fe80::a6b7:c914:44de:639  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 8  bytes 620 (620.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 752 (752.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

rmnet_ipa0: flags=65<UP,RUNNING>  mtu 2000
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 222785  bytes 381290027 (363.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 318303  bytes 69934418 (66.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 650238  bytes 739939859 (705.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 408284  bytes 63728624 (60.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/ether 3a:a0:1b:81:d4:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::38a0:1bff:fe81:d4f5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: rmnet_ipa0: <UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
5: rmnet_data0: <UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
    inet 10.140.58.138/30 scope global rmnet_data0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::93a5:ad99:4660:adc4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: rmnet_data1: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
7: rmnet_data2: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
8: rmnet_data3: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
9: rmnet_data4: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
10: rmnet_data5: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
11: rmnet_data6: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
12: rmnet_data7: <UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2000 qdisc htb state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
    inet6 fe80::a6b7:c914:44de:639/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: r_rmnet_data0: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
14: r_rmnet_data1: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
15: r_rmnet_data2: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
16: r_rmnet_data3: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
17: r_rmnet_data4: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
18: r_rmnet_data5: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
19: r_rmnet_data6: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
20: r_rmnet_data7: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
21: r_rmnet_data8: <> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/[530] 
22: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:d1:3a:07:70:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
23: p2p0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:d1:3a:07:70:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: @gilles-gouaillardet Executed (or rather not executed) on my Android phone. What permission error are you referring to? I did a Google search and I found a thread that mentions something about enabling loopback on the device. How do I do that? Is it relevant to my query?

Comment: Where do I update these permissions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229180/discussion-between-fernal73-and-gilles-gouaillardet).

Comment: you did not answer any of my questions so I cannot help you troubleshooting this issue. good speed.

Comment: From what I can see, one error is related to reading the MAC address. https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/opal/mca/if/posix_ipv4/if_posix.c

Comment: It does appear to be a "permission denied" error. That's what the error code 13 maps to according to method strerror.

Comment: What question are you referring to? No, I am not running OpenMPI within a container.

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.open-mpi.org//msg34374.html

Comment: Actually, you're right, Arch Linux on Termux does run in a Proot container.https://github.com/SDRausty/termux-archlinux

Answer (score 1):

Faced this problem on a laptop with Fedora 34. OpenMPI only worked with active Wifi connection. The problem was solved by adding the name of the loopback network interface for out-of-band communication to the file with system wide OpenMPI settings /etc/openmpi-x86_64/openmpi-mca-params.conf

```
oob_tcp_if_include = lo
```

Comment: I tried the above and tried to run IPyParallel using the MPI engine on Arch Linux on Termux and had the following response:2021-10-06 12:16:45.525 [IPClusterStart] WARNING | mpiexec error output:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
None of the TCP networks specified to be included for out-of-band communications
could be found:

  Value given: lo

Please revise the specification and try again.